# Compute interception of line with bounding box

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to cut a line to fit inside a bounding box.

I have a start and end point for the line, and the start and end dimensions of a bounding box.

I would like to have a function that to cut the part of the line that is outide the bounding box.

```
def intersection_with_BB(start_point, end_point, BB_bounds):
    direction = end_point - start_point
    length = np.linalg.norm(direction)

    n = [np.array([1, 0, 0]), np.array([-1, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0]), 
    np.array([0, -1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1]), np.array([0, 0, -1])]

    # something to check this
```

Sorry for the lack of code.

The end results would be.

```
P1 = np.array([-2, -2, 0.5])
P2 = np.array([2, 2, 0.5])
BB = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
result = intersection_with_BB(P1,P2,BB)
```

result should be the new start and end point that interpect the bounding box

Edit:
ChatGPT proposed this:

```
def compute_intersection(startPoint, endPoint, boundingBox):
    # calculate the direction vector of the line
    direction = endPoint - startPoint

    # initialize t values
    tmin = 0.0
    tmax = 1.0

    # loop over each axis of the bounding box
    for i in range(3):
        # check for parallelism
        if np.abs(direction[i]) == 0:
            # line is parallel to the plane
            if startPoint[i] < boundingBox[0][i] or startPoint[i] > boundingBox[1][i]:
                # line is outside the plane
                return None
        else:
            # calculate t values for intersection with plane
            t1 = (boundingBox[0][i] - startPoint[i]) / direction[i]
            t2 = (boundingBox[1][i] - startPoint[i]) / direction[i]

            # check ordering of t values
            if t1 > t2:
                t1, t2 = t2, t1

            # update tmin and tmax
            if t1 > tmin:
                tmin = t1
            if t2 < tmax:
                tmax = t2

            # check if intersection is empty
            if tmin > tmax:
                return None

    # calculate intersection point(s)
    intersection1 = startPoint + tmin * direction
    intersection2 = startPoint + tmax * direction

    # return intersection point(s)
    return intersection1, intersection2, np.linalg.norm(intersection2- intersection1)
```

Can anyone vouche for this?

Comment: it seems to work... is that chat-bot good for code generation?

Comment: This problem is old as the World. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm

Comment: I don't think you need to put what ChatGPT put. It's unnecessary, and I doubt people would read it. You aren't even allowed to answer questions with ChatGPT on this site.

Comment: @BlueRobin it was a suggestion made by the chatbot, not an answer. 
The answer I gave in the post bellow is based on the algorithm in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm for a 3D case. I had to had the other 2 dimensions "front" and "back". As the answer says: I would appreciate someone else's validation...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algebraic resolution of the question. Without loss of generality, we can assume one of the segment endpoints to be at the origin (otherwise, subtract its coordinates from all other coordinates).

Let `t δ` be the vector equation of the segment, with `0 ≤ t ≤ 1` and the window `[x, X].[y, Y].[z, Z]`.

We write the system of inequations

```
x ≤ t δx ≤ X
y ≤ t δy ≤ Y
z ≤ t δz ≤ Z
0 ≤ t ≤ 1
```

Assuming `δx, δy, δz > 0`, we transform to

```
x δy δz ≤ t δx δy δy ≤ X δy δz 
y δz δx ≤ t δx δy δy ≤ Y δz δx 
z δx δy ≤ t δx δy δy ≤ Z δx δy 
      0 ≤ t δx δy δy ≤ δx δy δy
```

or

```
max(x δy δz, y δz δx, z δx δy, 0) ≤ t δx δy δz ≤ min(X δy δz, Y δz δx, Z δx δz, δx δy δz).
```

If the left bound exceeds the right one, the segment is completely clipped out. Then, depending on which of the four arguments achieves the max/min, the endpoints are intersections with a side or the original endpoints.

The discussion must be completed for the other signs of the `δ`. It can be micro-optimized to avoid unnecessary divisions.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide some python code for a 3D case?

Comment: @ThomasJerry: sorry, for some reason I understood 2D.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

But, I would appreacite validation:
The algorithm is based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm for a 2D approach. Here extended to 3D.

Function takes the bounds as a numpy array containing the bounds of the domain and the and end point of a candidate point to clip if needed.

The algorithm should work by checking if both start and end point are inside the domain, it it is, returns the points. If it is not, it will clip the domain by applying 'y=mx + b'. The only uncertainty is if I did not make any mistake with the equations for the front and back:

**front:**

slope = (zDomain_max - zPoint_start) / (zPoint_end - zPoint_start)

x = xPoint_start + (xPoint_end - xPoint_start) * slope

y = yPoint_start + (yPoint_end - yPoint_start) * slope
z = zDomain_max

**back:**

slope = (zDomain_min - zPoint_start) / (zPoint_end - zPoint_start)

x = xPoint_start + (xPoint_end - xPoint_start) * slope

y = yPoint_start + (yPoint_end - yPoint_start) * slope

z = zDomain_min

```
import numpy as np

INSIDE  = 0  
LEFT = 1    
RIGHT = 2   
BOTTOM = 4  
TOP = 8     
BACK = 16   
FRONT = 32  

def compute_outcode(point, bounds):
    code = INSIDE
    if point[0] < bounds[0, 0]:
        code |= LEFT
    elif point[0] > bounds[1, 0]:
        code |= RIGHT
    if point[1] < bounds[0, 1]:
        code |= BOTTOM
    elif point[1] > bounds[1, 1]:
        code |= TOP
    if point[2] < bounds[0, 2]:
        code |= BACK
    elif point[2] > bounds[1, 2]:
        code |= FRONT
    return code

def cohen_sutherland_3d(start, end, bounds):

    outcode1 = compute_outcode(start, bounds)
    outcode2 = compute_outcode(end, bounds)
    
    while True:
        if ( outcode1 == 0 and outcode2 == 0):  # Both points inside the clipping region
            return start, end
        
        elif (outcode1 & outcode2) != 0:  # Both points outside the same clipping region
            return None, None
        
        else: # compute interception point
            x, y, z = 0, 0, 0
            outcode_out = outcode1 if outcode1 else outcode2
                      
            if outcode_out & LEFT:  # Clip against the left boundary
                slope = (bounds[0, 0] - start[0]) / (end[0] - start[0])
                x = bounds[0, 0]
                y = start[1] + (end[1] - start[1]) * slope  
                z = start[2] + (end[2] - start[2]) * slope
                
            elif outcode_out & RIGHT:  # Clip against the right boundary
                slope = (bounds[1, 0] - start[0]) / (end[0] - start[0])
                x = bounds[1, 0]
                y = start[1] + (end[1] - start[1]) * slope 
                z = start[2] + (end[2] - start[2]) * slope
            elif outcode_out & TOP:  # Clip against the top boundary
                slope = (bounds[1, 1] - start[1])/(end[1] - start[1])
                x = start[0] + (end[0] - start[0])*slope
                y = bounds[1, 1]
                z = start[2] + (end[2] - start[2]) *slope
            elif outcode_out & BOTTOM:  # Clip against the bottom boundary
                slope = (bounds[0, 1] - start[1]) / (end[1] - start[1])
                x = start[0] + (end[0] - start[0]) * slope
                y = bounds[0, 1]
                z = start[2] + (end[2] - start[2]) * slope
            elif outcode_out & FRONT:  # Clip against the front boundary
                slope = (bounds[1, 2] - start[2]) / (end[2] - start[2])
                x = start[0] + (end[0] - start[0]) * slope
                y = start[1] + (end[1] - start[1]) * slope
                z = bounds[1, 2]
            elif outcode_out & BACK:  # Clip against the back boundary
                slope = (bounds[0, 2] - start[2]) / (end[2] - start[2])
                x = start[0] + (end[0] - start[0]) * slope
                y = start[1] + (end[1] - start[1]) * slope
                z = bounds[0, 2]
                
        if outcode1:
            start=np.array([x,y,z])
            outcode1 = compute_outcode(start, bounds)
        else:
            end=np.array([x,y,z])
            outcode2 = compute_outcode(end, bounds)       
                
# Example

p1 = np.array([0,0,0])
p2 = np.array([0.2,0.2,0])

bounds = np.array([[0,0,0],[0.1,0.1,0]])

p1, p2 = cohen_sutherland_3d(p1,p2,bounds)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have added some context to the answer. Hope it is sufficient. If not, please let me know